# Using promise for an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

Is there anyway to use promise for `object` iteration?
Here's my source code.

```
 Object.keys(drop).map((key) => {
            RNGooglePlaces.lookUpPlaceByID(drop[key].placeID)
              .then((results) => {
                results.t = results.address;
                results.l = `${results.latitude},${results.longitude}`;
                array.push(results);
              })
              .catch((error) => reject(error));
 });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

This code above is not working because I have used Promise in `object.keys.map` function.

For getting the correct result of array, I think I have to use Promise for `Object.map`

I have used PromiseArrays for promise iteration but it doesn't work.

Is there any best solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, no value is `return`ed from `.map()` and `console.log(array)` is called outside of `Promise` chain. You can use `Promise.all()` and return a value from `.map()` to get an array of fulfilled `Promise` objects at `.then()`

```
 let promises = Promise.all(
                  Object.keys(drop).map(key => 
                    RNGooglePlaces.lookUpPlaceByID(drop[key].placeID)
                    .then(results => {
                      results.t = results.address;
                      results.l = `${results.latitude},${results.longitude}`;
                      return results;
                    })
                  )
                );
 promises.then(results => console.log(results))
 .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: One thing to remember is that Promise.all expects that all passed promises end up being resolved. In scenario when one of promises is rejected Promise.all will be rejected as whole

Comment: Very very thanks. Actually, I have tried promise.all, but it wasn't working. Now your code works charm. Highly recommended!!!